# How to read in two text files and count the amount of keywords?

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, io

I have tried looking around but, to me files are the hardest thing to understand so far as I am learning C, especially text files, binary files were a bit easier. Basically I have to read in two text files both contains words that are  formatted like this "hard, working,smart, works well, etc.." I am suppose to compare the text files and count the keywords. I would show some code but honestly I am lost and the only thing I have down is just nonsense besides this.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 1000

void resumeRater();
int main()
{

    int i;
    int counter = 0;

    char array[SIZE];
    char keyword[SIZE];

    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    int ch1, ch2;

    errno_t result1 = fopen_s(&fp1, "c:\\myFiles\\resume.txt", "r");
    errno_t result2 = fopen_s(&fp2, "c:\\myFiles\\ideal.txt", "r");
    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open");
    }
    else if (fp2 == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open");
    }
    else {
        result1 = fread(array, sizeof(char), 1, fp1);
        result2 = fread(keyword, sizeof(char), 1, fp2);
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] == keyword[i])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        fclose(fp1);
        fclose(fp2);
        printf("Character match: %d", counter);
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Well, you've figured out how to open the files. Perhaps the next step should be actually reading something from the opened files...

Comment: Yea I made some progress @twalberg I will add it to the question

Comment: You could do a hash table: read in all the words from one file and store them as keys for the hash table. Then for the values, you can go through the second file and takes the words from that file and compare them to keys in the hash table and, if there's a match, just add one to the value. Or, if that's too difficult, you could try using a linked list or an array and do the same thing, essentially.

Comment: @user3121023 its word, space word, space word, etc

Comment: Do you have a list of keywords you're supposed to be counting?

Comment: The keywords are in both text files organized in the same format they are any word I choose

Comment: `fread(array, sizeof(char), 1, fp1);`  read only one character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a situation where you are doing a **multiple of something** (like reading 2 files), it makes a lot of sense to plan ahead. Rather than muddying the body of `main` with all the code necessary to read 2 text files, create a function that reads the text file for you and have it return an array containing the lines of the file. This really helps you concentrate on the logic of what your code needs to do with the lines rather than filling space with getting the lines in the first place. Now there is nothing wrong with cramming it all in one long `main`, but from a readability, maintenance, and program structure standpoint, it makes all more difficult.

If you structure the read function well, you can reduce your `main` to the following. This reads both text files into character arrays and provides the number of lines read in a total of 4 lines (plus the check to make sure your provided two filenames to read):

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 3 ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s <filename1> <filename2>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    size_t file1_size = 0;  /* placeholders to be filled by readtxtfile */
    size_t file2_size = 0;  /* for general use, not needed to iterate   */

    /* read each file into an array of strings, 
    number of lines read, returned in file_size */
    char **file1 = readtxtfile (argv[1], &file1_size);
    char **file2 = readtxtfile (argv[2], &file2_size);

    return 0;
}
```

At that point you have all your data and you can work on your key word code. Reading from textfiles is a very simple matter. You just have to get comfortable with the tools available. When reading **lines** of text, the preferred approach is to use **line-input** to read an entire line at a time into a buffer. You then parse to buffer to get what it is you need. The line-input tools are `fgets` and `getline`. Once you have read the line, you then have tools like `strtok`, `strsep` or `sscanf` to separate what you want from the line. Both `fgets` and `getline` read the `newline` at the end of each line as part of their input, so you may need to remove the `newline` to meet your needs.

Storing each line read is generally done by declaring a pointer to an array of char* pointers. (e.g. `char **file1;`) You then allocate memory for some initial number of pointers. (`NMAX` in the example below) You then access the individual lines in the file as `file1_array[n]` when `n` is the line index `0 - lastline` of the file. If you have a large file and exceed the number of pointers you originally allocated, you simply reallocate additional pointers for your array with `realloc`. (you can set `NMAX` to 1 to make this happen for every line)

What you use to allocate memory and how you reallocate can influence how you make use of the arrays in your program. Careful choices of `calloc` to initially allocate your arrays, and then using `memset` when you reallocate to set all unused pointers to `0` (null), can really save you time and headache? Why? Because, to iterate over your array, all you need to do is:

```
n = 0; 
while (file1[n]) {
    <do something with file1[n]>; 
    n++;
}
```

When you reach the first unused pointer (i.e. the first `file1[n]` that is `0`), the loop stops.

Another very useful function when reading text files is `strdup (char *line)`. `strdup` will automatically allocate space for `line` using `malloc`, copy `line` to the newly allocated memory, and return a pointer to the new block of memory. This means that all you need to do to allocate space for each pointer and copy the line ready by `getline` to your array is:

```
file1[n] = strdup (line);
```

That's pretty much it. you have read your file and filled your array and know how to iterate over each line in the array. What is left is cleaning up and freeing the memory allocated when you no longer need it. By making sure that your unused pointers are `0`, this too is a snap. You simply iterate over your `file1[n]` pointers again, freeing them as you go, and then `free (file1)` at the end. Your done.

This is a lot to take in, and there are a few more things to it. On the initial read of the file, if you noticed, we also declare a `file1_size = 0;` variable, and pass its address to the read function:

```
char **file1 = readtxtfile (argv[1], &file1_size);
```

Within `readtxtfile`, the value at the address of `file1_size` is incremented by `1` each time a line is read. When `readtxtfile` returns, `file1_size` contains the number of lines read. As shown, this is not needed to iterate over the `file1` array, but you often need to know how many lines you have read.

To put this all together, I created a short example of the functions to read two text files, print the lines in both and free the memory associated with the file arrays. This explanation ended up longer than I anticipated. So take time to understand how it works, and you will be a step closer to handling textfiles easily. The code below will take 2 filenames as arguments (e.g. `./progname file1 file2`) Compile it with something similar to `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o progname srcfilename.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NMAX 256

char **readtxtfile (char *fn, size_t *idx);
char **realloc_char (char **p, size_t *n);
void prn_chararray (char **ca);
void free_chararray (char **ca);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 3 ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s <filename1> <filename2>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    size_t file1_size = 0;  /* placeholders to be filled by readtxtfile */
    size_t file2_size = 0;  /* for general use, not needed to iterate   */

    /* read each file into an array of strings, 
    number of lines read, returned in file_size */
    char **file1 = readtxtfile (argv[1], &file1_size);
    char **file2 = readtxtfile (argv[2], &file2_size);

    /* simple print function */
    if (file1) prn_chararray (file1);
    if (file2) prn_chararray (file2);

    /* simple free memory function */
    if (file1) free_chararray (file1);
    if (file2) free_chararray (file2);

    return 0;
}

char** readtxtfile (char *fn, size_t *idx)
{
    if (!fn) return NULL;           /* validate filename provided       */

    char *ln = NULL;                /* NULL forces getline to allocate  */
    size_t n = 0;                   /* max chars to read (0 - no limit) */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;               /* number of chars actually read    */
    size_t nmax = NMAX;             /* check for reallocation           */
    char **array = NULL;            /* array to hold lines read         */
    FILE *fp = NULL;                /* file pointer to open file fn     */

    /* open / validate file */
    if (!(fp = fopen (fn, "r"))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: file open failed '%s'.", __func__, fn);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* allocate NMAX pointers to char* */
    if (!(array = calloc (NMAX, sizeof *array))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: memory allocation failed.", __func__);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* read each line from fp - dynamicallly allocated   */
    while ((nchr = getline (&ln, &n, fp)) != -1)
    {
        /* strip newline or carriage rtn    */
        while (nchr > 0 && (ln[nchr-1] == '\n' || ln[nchr-1] == '\r'))
            ln[--nchr] = 0;

        array[*idx] = strdup (ln);  /* allocate/copy ln to array        */

        (*idx)++;                   /* increment value at index         */

        if (*idx == nmax)           /* if lines exceed nmax, reallocate */
            array = realloc_char (array, &nmax);
    }

    if (ln) free (ln);              /* free memory allocated by getline */
    if (fp) fclose (fp);            /* close open file descriptor       */

    return array;
}

/* print an array of character pointers. */
void prn_chararray (char **ca)
{
    register size_t n = 0;
    while (ca[n])
    {
        printf (" arr[%3zu]  %s\n", n, ca[n]);
        n++;
    }
}

/* free array of char* */
void free_chararray (char **ca)
{
    if (!ca) return;
    register size_t n = 0;
    while (ca[n])
        free (ca[n++]);
    free (ca);
}

/*  realloc an array of pointers to strings setting memory to 0.
*  reallocate an array of character arrays setting
*  newly allocated memory to 0 to allow iteration
*/
char **realloc_char (char **p, size_t *n)
{
    char **tmp = realloc (p, 2 * *n * sizeof *p);
    if (!tmp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: reallocation failure.\n", __func__);
        // return NULL;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    p = tmp;
    memset (p + *n, 0, *n * sizeof *p); /* memset new ptrs 0 */
    *n *= 2;

    return p;
}
```

**valgrind - Don't Forget To Check For Leaks**

Lastly, anytime you allocate memory in your code, make sure you use a memory checker such as `valgrind` to confirm you have no memory errors and to confirm you have no memory leaks (i.e. allocated blocks you have forgotten to free, or that have become unreachable). `valgrind` is simple to use, just `valgrind ./progname [any arguments]`. It can provide a wealth of information. For example, on this read example:

```
$ valgrind ./bin/getline_readfile_fn voidstruct.c wii-u.txt
==14690== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14690== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14690== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14690== Command: ./bin/getline_readfile_fn voidstruct.c wii-u.txt
==14690==
        <snip - program output>
==14690==
==14690== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14690==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14690==   total heap usage: 61 allocs, 61 frees, 6,450 bytes allocated
==14690==
==14690== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==14690==
==14690== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14690== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Pay particular attention to the lines:

```
==14690== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

and

```
==14690== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

You can ignore the `(suppressed: 2 from 2)` which just indicate I don't have the development files installed for libc.